# Box model issue with the new filter bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-nav

The HTML of the new filter bar looks like this:

```
<div id="filter-bar">
  <div class="tag-filter"> ... </div>       
  <div class="filter-bar-links"> ... </div>
  <div class="layout-settings"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Here, `tag-filter` and `filter-bar-links` have height 38px. The containing div `filter-bar` is also given height 38px **but** this includes 1px bottom-border. So the height available for its contents is only 37px. As a result, the inner divs protrude vertically out of their container, potentially messing up the layout of other elements.

This does not happen *yet* because there is still enough horizontal room in the layout. But once the interface is localized to a language with longer tab names, there may be a surprise:

[image: chrome]

(Tab renamed with Chrome dev tools).